# Subclass Interval for dateutil.relativedelta support in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i'am trying to implement basic support for relative dateranges (months, years) in sqlalchemy. using postgres as database i thought subclassing sqlalchemy.dialects.postgres.Interval and changing the returned python type to dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta would be the best/quickest way.

```
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgres import INTERVAL
from dateutil import relativedelta

class DateInterval(INTERVAL):
    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        def process(value):
            return value
        return process

@property
def python_type(self):
    return relativedelta.relativedelta


class MyInterval(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateInterval

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        result = ''
        for attr in ["years", "months", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"]:
            tempvalue = getattr(value, attr)
            if tempvalue:
                result += "%s %s " % (tempvalue, attr)
        return result

    def process_result_value(self, value, engine):
        return value

    @property
    def python_type(self):
        return relativedelta.relativedelta
```

Flushing to db works as expected, the process_bind_param method works. 
Fetching it afterwards, does not. The value argument in the process function of the result_processor method is already a timedelta object. Where to hook in, to process the raw values to relativedelta objects?
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psycopg2 is returning those timedeltas.  If you want to intercept those, you'd need to augment things at the psycopg2 level: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects  perhaps you can use new_type() to circumvent psycopg2's default type converter for INTERVAL objects.

step one would be to get the raw value back from a plain psycopg2 connection/cursor to make sure you have control at that level.

then when you've figured out how to get that, you can intercept newly created psycopg2 connection objects and set up the adapters you want within the [connect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.connect) event.